# Material design navigation drawer footer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-design

I want to pin two options on the bottom of my navigation drawer.  Like in this picture

[image: Navigation drawer with pinned options]

If it's possible I would like to pin my header too. I am building my navigation drawer with the support design lib.